# Inconsistent tags

Tags: support, retag-request

I just asked a question about netbeans and found the names of tags as

netbeans6.5
netbeans6.7
netbeans6.8
netbeans-6.9
netbeans-7

Last two names have added a '-' before version number. A '-' should be added to all five.

Comment: Or '-' should be removed from the last two.

Comment: Should it be `netbeans-7` or `netbeans-7.0`?